# Docker app not able to communicate with database container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have mysql DB running in a container and web app running in another container. My use case is once the DB container is up and running app container has to insert some initial data to DB using Liquibase and start the app. My docker yml looks like below.

```
db:
    build: kdb
    user: "1000:50"
    volumes:
      - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    container_name: kdb
    environment:  
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    image:  kdb
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"



k-api:
    container_name: k_api
    hostname: k-api
    domainname: i.com
    image:  k_api
    volumes:
      - /Users/agu/work:/data
    build:
      context:  ./api
      args:
        KB_API_WAR: k-web-1.2.9.war 
        KB_API_URL: https://artifactory.b-aws.i.com
    ports:  
      - "8097:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    #command: [/usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh, "db:3306","-s","-t","0","--","/bin/sh" "wait_for_liquibase.sh"]
    links:
      - "db:kdb_docker_host"
```

And in my Dockerfile for api i have entry point for a shell script called "wait_for_liquibase.sh"

```
CMD ["wait_for_liquibase.sh"]
```

wait_for_liquibase.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e


#RUN liquibase
mvn clean install -X  -PdropAll -Dcontexts=test -Dliquibase.user=XX -Dliquibase.pass=XX -Dliquibase.host=db -Dliquibase.port=3306 -Dliquibase.schema=knowledgebasedb -DpromptOnNonLocalDatabase=false -Dcontexts=test -f k/k-liquibase

/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

**The issue is once the DB container is up and running app container is not able to reach the DB server to perform liquibase setup for database. I see the below error.**

**Communication failure: Unknown database host -Dliquibase.host=db.**

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using version 1.

You giving an alias to your "db" service, you will need to use that alias, `kdb_docker_host`

Also, the ports are mapping to the host machine, to expose ports between containers yuo will need to use the `expose` property.

```
expose:
  - 3306
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this in Docker file `RUN         apt-get update
RUN         apt-get install netcat -y
ADD         wait-for-base.sh /wait-for-base.sh
CMD         ["/wait-for-base.sh"]`

and in wait-for-base.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

while ! nc -z db 3306; do sleep 3; done
[my command to run]
```

In your case `/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run`